# WebRTC ios Setup

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am trying to setup video call in my iOS app, for which I'm using WebRTC.
I have followed the link: 
http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios
& the setup is successful.
But, the output file that WebRTC provides is .app file instead of .ipa.
I have also tried to convert .app file to .ipa, i am not able to install this app, app always remains in installing state.
So is there any issue with the output .app file that WebRTC provides or is there any specific method to install this app file.

Comment: Do you want to run AppRTCDemo on your devices?

Comment: Yes.! It was successful.

Comment: I had followed : https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts
This is very good demonstration of WebRTC ios.
But now i want to implement WebRTC video calling in my own ios app.

Comment: https://github.com/otalk

Answer (score 4):

The best choice to start a webrtc app on iOS is to use the official sample app : https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/

Since it's not so easy to build it with Xcode, it can be easier to start from https://github.com/crossle/AppRTCMobile. It's based on February 2018 webrtc code.

you just have to take the project, compile it and install the perfectly working app on your iPhone.

It's using the apprtc signalling server. The source is at https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc.

If you want to try to create your own Xcode project, the best is to use cocoaPods lib from google: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

Answer (score 0):

use cocoa pods to get libjingle_peerconnection pod. It is the best way to proceed with webRTC ios application.

Then You just need to implement features from the link you are referring.

You can refer https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppRTC and get started.